# Setting Probes for SimVision in SystemVerilog Code

Tags: cadence

I'm trying to probe the systemverilog signals by using irun .
I came across the some example to dump wave as the below ,when I googling.

```
 initial begin                                                                 
     $recordfile("sv_wave");                                                  
     $recordvars("depth=all",pstest);                                         
  end
```

It seems work but the other variables can't see the value with "No Value Available".

I use the below script to run the simulation.

```
irun \                                                                         
    +access+wrc \                                                              
    -cdn_vip_root /u572/cadence/installs/VIPCAT113 \                     
    /u572/sv/denaliMem.sv \
    /u572/sv/denaliCdn_ahb.sv \    
    /u572/svExamples/simpleExample/hdl/master_mux.v \
    /u572/svExamples/simpleExample/hdl/slave_mux.v \
    hdl/ahb_verilog.v \                                                        
    test2.v \
    tb.sv \                                                                    
    -incdir /u572/svExamples/simpleExample \
    -timescale 1ps/1ps -top pstest
```

What am I supposed to do to get the variable's value of the No Value Available variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the simulator side, the command you can use is `probe -create <signal> <options>`. You can either type that in the irun `simulator` console or provide as an instruction in the `.tcl` file at startup. Refer to the documentation provided with the simulator under the section `Simulator Tcl Commands` / `probe` for verbose description & examples.